# How can i download angular2 release candidate from npm or jspm

Tags: angular

If i try to download angular2 from npm or jspm

```
npm i angular2 --save
jspm install npm:angular2
```

I am getting `angular@^2.0.0-beta.17` instead of `2.0.0-rc.1` . Has this got something to do with the changes in the release candidate or have the packages just not been updated?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install from NodeJS :

```
npm install --save @angular/core @angular/compiler @angular/common @angular/platform-browser @angular/platform-browser-dynamic rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 zone.js@0.6.12
```

And if you want to force the version, you can add @2.0.0-rc.1, like this :

```
npm install @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1
```

Comment: If `@angular/core` and `@angular/compiler` are basically dependent on one another why would they make them separate downloads . or at least config a most use standard download? installing with `jspm install npm:@angular/core` you do get rxjs and zone.js  .... with is nice i guess. seems a little verbose for the ideals of package managers. thanks though ✔

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in angular.io documentation, mention the rc version in the dependency:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.9",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^0.8.1"
  }
}
```

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: That's not fun though. If i want to quickly add angular 2 then i must type all of that. ideally it should be `npm install angular2` or `npm install @angular` or `jspm install @angluar` automation for the win

Comment: if you want to add a package on the go, then just follow the way NPM says like `npm install <package-name>@<version>`. example: `npm install @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1`. And I am sure this will work. :)